# How to save csv data into .csv file in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

This is my "app.js" file.

```
const { convertArrayToCSV } = require('convert-array-to-csv');
const converter = require('convert-array-to-csv');
const fs = require('fs')
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const randomWords = require('random-words')
const header = ['number', 'first', 'last', 'handle'];

const dataArrays = [
[1, 'Mark', 'Otto', '@mdo'],
[2, 'Jacob', 'Thornton', '@fat'],
[3, 'Larry', 'the Bird', '@twitter'],
];
const val = convertArrayToCSV(dataArrays, {
header,
separator: ','
});
console.log(val)
```

**output:**

```
number,first,last,handle
1,Mark,Otto,@mdo  
2,Jacob,Thornton,@fat
3,Larry,the Bird,@twitter
```

I  want to save this "Val" as a .csv file on my device.
How can I do that? Please help. I am stuck here for the last 4 hours.

Comment: filesystem fs library and there the function writeFile

Comment: I use writefile function but failed.

Comment: @Mujahidaul Islam
as your convertArrayToCSV results in an string it should work

Comment: it could be that you need write access to the directory where you will create the file. 
You can check this in unix enviroment with ls -al
Or do as path your home folder 
`/home/newcsvfile.csv` 
`~/newcsvfile.csv`

Answer (score 3):

#### File System Library

To achieve this you can use the [File System Library of NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)

Data can be:  `<string> | <Buffer> | <TypedArray> | <DataView> | <Object>`

As option you can parse an encoding like

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node.js', 'utf8', callback);


const { convertArrayToCSV } = require('convert-array-to-csv');
const converter = require('convert-array-to-csv');
const fs = require('fs')
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const randomWords = require('random-words')
const header = ['number', 'first', 'last', 'handle'];

const dataArrays = [
[1, 'Mark', 'Otto', '@mdo'],
[2, 'Jacob', 'Thornton', '@fat'],
[3, 'Larry', 'the Bird', '@twitter'],
];
const val = convertArrayToCSV(dataArrays, {
header,
separator: ','
});
console.log(val)


fs.writeFile('<pathtodirectory>/message.csv', val, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('The file has been saved!');
    });
```

Comment: You‘re welcome :) of you think this was helpful mark it as accepted, the button below up / down vote.

Comment: I don't enough reputation for voting. It needs a minimum of 15 reputations to vote.

Comment: Accepting is possible with any rep. You can choose one of your answers as helpful then other people see this helped solving the problem. Ist is the greyed out check below the up down button

Answer (score 2):

```
const fs = require('fs')
const header = ['number', 'first', 'last', 'handle'];

const dataArrays = [
[1, 'Mark', 'Otto', '@mdo'],
[2, 'Jacob', 'Thornton', '@fat'],
[3, 'Larry', 'the Bird', '@twitter'],
];

const val = [header].concat(dataArrays).map(arr => arr.join(',')).join('\r\n');

fs.writeFile('filename.csv', val, err => {
  if(err) console.error(err);
  else console.log('Ok');
}););
```

Comment: Thank's for your time and  effort   .

Comment: Works. Thank you.